# clean repetitive javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just want to know if I can make this repetitive javascript code smaller, since I am going to end up with a lot of lists but with different content for each link. https://jsfiddle.net/sandiie/zma424f8/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( '.none' ).hide();
   $('.b01').click(function(){
   var list_new = $('#list_new01').html();
   $('#list').empty().append(list_new);
       $( '.b01' ).hide();
});

$( '.none' ).hide();
   $('.b02').click(function(){
   var list_new = $('#list_new02').html();
   $('#list').empty().append(list_new);
       $( '.b02' ).hide();
   });

});

<ul id="list">
    <li class="b01"><a href="#">Blah1</a></li>
    <li class="b02"><a href="#">Blah2</a></li>
    <li class="b03"><a href="#">Blah3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="list_new01" class="none">
    <li><a href="#">Blah1-01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blah1-02</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="list_new02" class="none">
    <li><a href="#">Blah2-01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blah2-02</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Questions regarding code review should be posted in the appropriate Stack Exchange community: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zma424f8/1/

Comment: sorry, I didn't know but thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that calling `$( '.none' ).hide();` twice is unnecessary.

Since this is the same type of functionality, add the same class to each of the elements for the click function. Then you want to match it to the list, one way to do this is through a matching attribute so it can be selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // it might be better to set this in your css with display:none
    $('.none').hide();

    $('.b a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var list_new = $('ul.' + id).html();
        $('#list').empty().append(list_new);
        $(this).parents('li').hide();
    });

});
```

I updated your HTML as well, which you can view in the fiddle, but this is the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/zma424f8/2/